# Definining a metric on a locally-finite simplicial complex's geometric realization

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, geometric-topology

Let $K$ be a locally-finite simplicial complex; that is there is no vertex in $K$'s vertex set which belongs to infinitely many simplices in $K$.  As usual, let $|K|$ denote $K$'s geometric realization.  In [Proposition 4.2.16 (2) of "Geometric Aspects of General Topology" by Katsuro Sakai](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-4-431-54397-8.pdf) it is stated that $K$ is l*ocally finite if and only if it is metrizable* (and a proof sketch is given).

My question is, suppose additionally that $K$ is a finite set so that $|K|$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^{2\#K+1}$; then can we construct a metric $d$ on $|K|$ inducing $|K|$'s topology by simply restricting the Euclidean metric to $|K|$?  In particular, simplices in $|K|$ are then geodesically convex under $d$ no?

*NB, I guess if $K$ is countably infinite then by we can simply assume that $|K|$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with its usual Fréchet metric?*

Comment: What's a problem with doing so?

Comment: Which definition of $\lvert K \rvert$ does Sakai use?